# 20.04 Server Install not booting on low memory VM

Tags: server, ram, 20.04

tried to boot the live dvd installer for 20.04 server on virtualbox with 512MB of RAM on 2 seperate machines. There is a kernel panic after select install Ubuntu server. This amount of memory worked fine for 18.04 server. Works when changed to 1024MB. Any reason why I can't have 512MB for small servers that need very little memory?

[image]

Comment: The 'live' system requires memory for 'live' to run, plus installer.  Are you comparing a 'live' ISO to a *debian-installer* non-live system?

Comment: I'm not sure what the 'live' means, they're the only server installers available for 18.04 and 20.04. I did however resize the memory for the 18.04 server down to 512 MB, so maybe the installer does require more RAM initially?

Comment: The default server in 18.04 (initial release) was the *di* or *debian-installer*; it's purpose was to install system only, and didn't allow 'live' mode for fixing system which is now the default. The 'live' installer requires more memory as 'live' needs RAM (700mb was minimum for 18.04 Lubuntu 'live' mode, I don't know 20.04 live installer sorry) plus you need RAM for installer. I suspect you're comparing different installer options (*di* for 18.04 & 'live' or`subiquity` for 20.04)  https://ubuntu.com/server/docs  You'll note 512MB is minimum for di installer, 1GB for 'live' installer

Comment: Just been to cdimage.ubuntu.com and found the images for bionic are not consistent with the images at releases.ubuntu.com. This is confusing. Looks like I will be dealing with the live installer from now on then :(

Comment: There are multiple install options, in 18.04 (original & subsequent till it changed, and I can't recall if that was 18.04.4 which would mean to 18.04.3) the *di* or standard installer was default.  Ubuntu 20.04 now has the 'live' installer default (as I suspect 18.04.4 used, but I could be wrong as I haven't checked), so the difference is the default installer (which is usually downloaded; look at your alternative installers).

Answer (score 2):

Glad to see I'm not the only one with this issue. I'm creating a template with a low-memory VM (512M) and now it's not enough (it was with Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 16.04).

The issue is linked to the version of the image you are using. For Ubuntu 20.04 (and I don't understand why/how), the only version available is the "live" (using more memory).

You can download images from two endpoints.

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/20.04/release/
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/20.04/

For Ubuntu 20.04, it seems that the difference is that "releases" is hosting amd64 versions (desktop, server live BUT no server non-live version) and "cdimage" is hosting everything else.

However, previously this was not the case

- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/18.04/release/
- http://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04/

"Non-live" versions are deprecated but sill available under the ["ubuntu-server-legacy" section](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-legacy-server/releases/20.04/release/).

More official information can be found at https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/server-installer-plans-for-20-04-lts/13631.

Wait & see.